# How to enable sync on suspend?

Tags: suspend

I have this weird issue with my PC running Linux Mint: every once in a while my computer won't wake up from sleep. Long story short - I think I figured out what's wrong. Kinda. At least I know how to fix it. Also kinda

For some reason that I don't understand, when I do `sync` right before I suspend the PC it always wakes up. So when I want to suspend my PC now I type in terminal:

```
sudo sh -c "sync && pm-suspend"
```

Like I said, it does work (and I checked it more than 100 times - without that `sync` my PC won't wake up after about 15 sleep-resume cycles, so 100 or so is enough evidence for me), however when I suspend my PC this way I need to type in my password (because `pm-suspend` requires root privileges) and also it doesn't work with automatic suspension (after certain amount of time my PC will automatically suspend, so it won't be wasting electricity). So now my question is - how can I make the PC automatically do `sync` right before suspending itself?

I tried the simplest solution I could think of - that is: adding a simple alias in my `.bashrc` file (and also root's file too, to be sure). So I added this command at the end of the file:

```
alias pm-suspend='sync && pm-suspend'
```

But it doesn't work. I checked and it's like I haven't done anything to address the issue.

So, I dig through the Internet and I found some interesting things. [Turns out that there was a time when the `sync` on suspend was automatic, but it was made optional in the Linux kernel.](https://lwn.net/Articles/582648/) Also, [there is a file that controls whether or not the `sync` command will be invoked.](https://lkml.org/lkml/2020/1/16/310) I'm not sure what to call those sites (documentation?), but here's a quote from the second link:

```
    /sys/power/sync_on_suspend

    Description:
    This file controls whether or not the kernel will sync()
    filesystems during system suspend (after freezing user space
    and before suspending devices).

    Writing a "1" to this file enables the sync() and writing a
    "0" disables it.  Reads from the file return the current value.
    The default is "1" but can be configured with the build-time
    config flag "SUSPEND_SKIP_SYNC".
```

I'm kinda a noob in this regards, but if I understand correctly there is a compile flag, "SUSPEND_SKIP_SYNC", but it can only be set when compiling the kernel manually. Am I right? Also, the file that it mentions - well, it's not in my system. I tried creating it manually, but I can't and if I understand correctly you shouldn't even be able to create files in `/sys`. Is that also right? If so, then how can I enable that automatic `sync` on suspend?

So, now I've come a stop. I don't really know what to do next, what to check. I wouldn't consider myself experienced and knowledgeable in the ways of Linux and Unix, so I'm kindly asking you to help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

No, the text you quoted is telling you that if you write a `1` to `/sys/power/sync_on_suspend` then it  will enable sync on suspend without having to recompile the kernel.  This is as simple as running the following as root:

```
echo 1 > /sys/power/sync_on_suspend
```

or, as a non-root user with `sudo` access:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/power/sync_on_suspend > /dev/null
```

There are many ways you can set this up to happen automatically on boot, including writing a shell script to run at boot time, or writing a systemd unit file to do the same.

Comment: I know what it says, but thank you for confirming it. I tried doing what you suggest even before you said it. I just didn't include it in the post. But yeah, it doesn't work. It says: `/sys/power/sync_on_suspend: Permission denied`. You see, the problem is that there is no file named `sync_on_suspend` in my `/sys/power/` folder. I already tried creating it with `touch` (as root, of course), but it also doesn't work. Like I said - I don't think you should be able to create files in `/sys` directory. It's not that simple as to create that file and write `1` to it - because you can't.